# Using PHPCoord to convert OS Map references to Lat Lon

Tags: php, maps, coordinates

I've managed to install the vast and clever [PHPCoord](https://phpcoord.net/) and have successfully executed some of the [examples](https://phpcoord.net/en/stable/coordinate_conversions_easy.html) provided. However I'm really struggling with the documentation and cannot suss out how to get it to convert OS Map references which I think are known as [OSGB36](https://phpcoord.net/en/stable/builtin_crs_geographic2d.html#osgb36) to typical Latitude and Longitude which I think are [WGS_84](https://phpcoord.net/en/stable/builtin_crs_geographic2d.html#wgs-84).

My first issue is that it seems I can only offer up two values in meters (metres), which means I first need to convert the two letters at the start of the reference and then split up the reference into two values. I can do this fairly painlessly so not too much of a problem, however I'm still unable to successfully convert.

Here's my code so far:

```php
use PHPCoord\CoordinateReferenceSystem\Geographic2D;
use PHPCoord\CoordinateReferenceSystem\Projected;
use PHPCoord\ProjectedPoint;
use PHPCoord\UnitOfMeasure\Length\Metre;
$from = ProjectedPoint::createFromEastingNorthing(
    Projected::fromSRID(Projected::EPSG_OSGB36_BRITISH_NATIONAL_GRID),
    new Metre(374600),
    new Metre(250400)
);
$toCRS = Projected::fromSRID(Geographic2D::EPSG_WGS_84);
$to = $from->convert($toCRS); 
echo $to;
```

This provides the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught
> PHPCoord\Exception\UnknownCoordinateReferenceSystemException: Unknown
> SRID: urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326

The idea is I take an OS Map reference like SO746504 and convert it to 52.151293, -2.3726484. I'm working on the basis I need to first convert it to an Easting Northing value (outside of PHPCoord), in this instance 374600, 250400 and then convert.

This is uncharted territory for me and I'm really struggling so any pointers would be massively appreciated.

Currently using [gridreferencefinder.com](https://gridreferencefinder.com/) to convert for cross reference, in case it assists anyone.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of digging and hours of trial and error I came up with a working solution. I thought I'd post here in the interest of helping out someone else struggling with this.

The first part was converting the OS Map reference to easting northing values. Here's the function I came up with:

```php
function osgb_to_en( $coordinate ) {
    $en = null;
    $easting = null;
    $northing = null;
    $coordinate = sanitize_text_field($coordinate); // Removes tags, line breaks, tabs and extra whitespace
    $coordinate = strtoupper($coordinate); // Convert to uppercase just in case
    // Now let us break it down into seperate elements
    $numbers = preg_replace('/[A-Z]/','', $coordinate); // Get the numbers by replacing alpha characters with nothing
    $letters = preg_replace('/[0-9]/','', $coordinate); // Get the letters by replacing numeric characters with nothing

    // Now lets deal with the number element
    if( is_numeric( $numbers ) ) {
        $middle = strlen( $numbers ) / 2; // Work out the middle position
        $easting = substr( $numbers, 0, $middle ); // Get the number from 0 position to middle
        $northing = substr( $numbers, $middle ); // Get the number from middle position onwards.
        if( mb_strlen ( $numbers ) < '10' ) {
            $easting = str_pad($easting , 5, '0', STR_PAD_RIGHT); // Add zeroes to the end of the string to bring it up to desired length
            $northing = str_pad($northing, 5, '0', STR_PAD_RIGHT);
        }
    }
    if( $letters ) {
        // Now for the two digit number element
        $osgb_ref = array(
            array('NA',0,9),array('NB',1,9),array('NC',2,9),array('ND',3,9),array('NF',0,8),array('NG',1,8),array('NH',2,8),array('NJ',3,8),array('NK',4,8),array('NL',0,7),array('NM',1,7),array('NN',2,7),array('NO',3,7),array('NR',1,6),array('NS',2,6),array('NT',3,6),array('NU',4,6),array('NW',1,5),array('NX',2,5),array('NY',3,5),array('NZ',4,5),array('SC',2,4),array('SD',3,4),array('SE',4,4),array('TA',5,4),array('SH',2,3),array('SJ',3,3),array('SK',4,3),array('TF',5,3),array('TG',6,3),array('SM',2,2),array('SN',2,2),array('SO',3,2),array('SP',4,2),array('TL',5,2),array('TM',6,2),array('SR',1,1),array('SS',2,1),array('ST',3,1),array('SU',4,1),array('TQ',5,1),array('TR',6,1),array('SV',0,0),array('SW',1,0),array('SX',2,0),array('SY',3,0),array('SZ',4,0),array('TV',5,0),array('HP',4,12),array('HT',3,11),array('HU',4,11),array('HY',3,10),array('HZ',4,10)
        ); // This is an array of the 100km squares covering Great Britain 
        // Loop through the array to find a match and prepend to exisitng easting and northing values
        foreach( $osgb_ref as $value ) {
            if ( $value[0] == $letters ) {
                $easting = $value[1] . $easting;
                $northing = $value[2] . $northing;
            }
        }
    }
    // If we have values combine them into an array and return
    if( $easting && $northing ) {
        $en = array(
            'easting' => $easting,
            'northing' => $northing
        );
    }
    return $en;
}
```

Once we have the pair of values we can use PHPCoord to get the latitude and longitude:

```php
use PHPCoord\CoordinateReferenceSystem\Projected;
use PHPCoord\ProjectedPoint;
use PHPCoord\UnitOfMeasure\Length\Metre;
use PHPCoord\CoordinateReferenceSystem\Geographic2D;

$osgb_to_en = osgb_to_en( 'SO7188142735' );
$easting = $osgb_to_en['easting'];
$northing = $osgb_to_en['northing'];
$from = ProjectedPoint::createFromEastingNorthing(
    Projected::fromSRID(Projected::EPSG_OSGB36_BRITISH_NATIONAL_GRID),
    new Metre($easting),
    new Metre($northing)
);
$toCRS = Geographic2D::fromSRID(Geographic2D::EPSG_WGS_84); //GPS/Google maps
$point = $from->convert($toCRS);
$latitude = $point->getLatitude()->asDegrees()->getValue();
$longitude = $point->getLongitude()->asDegrees()->getValue();
echo $latitude . ',' . $longitude;
```

This is all tested and working with PHP 8.0 and version 5.2.0 of PHPCoord.